# Specify unsupported devices

Tags: ios, titanium

Is there a way to specify devices that are not supported by my titanium app under ios?

I need to limit support to iPhone 5+, completely remove any ipad support & possibly allow only iOS version 7+.

How can I do it? Is there a way to define this in the tiapp.xml?

Comment: You cant limit to iPhone 5+ - if you have an iPhone app then your app will be available on all iPhones that support your minimum deployment version - so if you specified iOS 8 that would be 4S and above. For older versions you will also support iPhone 4

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, and how can I specify the minimum ios version?

Comment: In titanium, I don't know. In Xcode it is right there on the project settings

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you can limit your app to one specific phone but I believe that Paulw11 is right.

However here is some code to specify a minimum iOs version:

Add this to your tiapp.xml

```
<ios>
    <min-ios-ver>8.0</min-ios-ver>
</ios>
```

Replace `8.0` with whatever you need. Have a look at [this question](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152252/how-to-set-the-minimum-ios-target-version) over at the titanium forum for more details.